# Any recommendation for a monitor that works painless with a Macbook Pro?

Tags: monitors, macbook

I have a Macbook Pro 16 inches with an Intel processor (2020) and I recently bought a 27 inches external monitor from Philips that was supposed to make my life easier at work.

But there were a lot of troubles and the monitor kept disconnecting, only the HDMI connection worked (not USB-C or USB-B), plus the monitor kept disconnecting. I tried a lot of stuff like restarting, re-attaching the cable but it was disconnecting every few minutes so it wasn't practical for me to use it. So in the end after losing several hours on it I have decided to return it.

I understand that it's not necessarily only a monitor's problem, but from one side Apple's software could having compatibility problems. I made a research online and the thing is that the amount of potential things that you could do to fix these problems are infinite, form resetting your NVRAM to installing the latest drivers, etc... but I want to avoid that because I don't have much time to spend on it, specially considering that I am supposed to work for my company and not for my monitor xD

Does anybody have a recommendation for a 27 inches monitor that is painless and compatible with Apple's MacBook (something plug and play without the need for restarting, or disconnecting and reattaching the cable every once in a while), with a budget around 300€?

Comment: There's no such thing as a 2020 16" intel, only a [2019](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP809?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). According to Apple's spec it doesn't have HDMI, only Thunderbolt - which likely make it a cabling/hub mismatch, not the computer. Pretty much any 27" made since 2012 should be compatible, with the correct adapters/cables.

Comment: Indeed it was with the adapter and I just checked, you are right about the year. If you speak about compatibility I think that you misunderstood my question. Many monitors are compatible but they show lags and they disconnect and you have to manually reattach the cable.